# Gerena Free Fire topup api using player id only

Tags: google-play-games

I have seen alot of websites which make diamond topup to free fire account using only player id.
I looked for API in free fire website but I havent found any api like that and free fire does not allow to transfer diamond.

How can I topup diamond to another account. Is there any api or any solutions ?

Comment: I protected this question because frankly I do not see how it can attract anything other than spam like the one below which was just deleted. Please convince me that this post (as old as it is) really is meant according to [ask] and on-topic for this programming community.